# global $woocommerce; in wordpress my-ac-plugin.php 500 error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to add 'global $woocommerce;' in the wordpress my-ac-plugin.php to pull in the users country code for my caching but I'm getting a 500 error.

Does anyone know how I can do this, or any ideas what's wrong?

Here's my code...

```
if (!defined('WPINC')) {
exit('Do NOT access this file directly.');
}
function my_ac_plugin() 
{
$ac = $GLOBALS['comet_cache_advanced_cache']; 
$ac->addFilter('comet_cache_version_salt', 
'my_ac_version_salt_shaker');
}
function my_ac_version_salt_shaker($version_salt)
{

global $woocommerce;
$customer_country = $woocommerce->customer->get_country();
$version_salt .= $customer_country; 
geoip_close($gi);
return $version_salt;

}
my_ac_plugin();
```

Comment: First, check your error.log for the 500 error in `/var/log/apache` or `var/log/nginx` (depend on the type of web server you are using).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked that and it doesn't show the errors. Currently it shows errors but just not for this. I'm not sure if it's because the file is my-ac-plugin.php

Comment: Internal Server error 500 could be a lot of things, ranging from permission denied to parsing/syntax error. a) If you are creating an plug-in `my-ac-plugin.php`, make sure it has the correct permission. b) Reboot the system and see if you still have the error 500. I can only guess this because you didn't provide enough information for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to help in troubleshooting:

1. Go **FTP** into your website
2. Open the file named **wp-config.php**
3. Find the line where you see `define('WP_DEBUG', false);`
4. Change **false** to **true** and save the file

The next time you refresh the page you were getting an error on you should now see more descriptive error messages which will help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks CKG. That helped get an error. The error is 

"Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/wordpress/wp-content/ac-plugins/my-ac-plugin.php on line 14 Fatal error: Call to a member function get_country() on null in /home/wordpress/wp-content/ac-plugins/my-ac-plugin.php on line 14”. 

The line is - $customer_country = $woocommerce->customer->get_country();.

I use the same code in footer.php just before the closing body tag and it works correctly.